# PowerShell Script Reading Xml File and Still Throwing Exceptions

Tags: xml, powershell

Currently, I had to alter an XML file from XML version 1.1 to 1.0 to be able to read the file.  Upon doing so I was able to read the XML file and pull the information I wanted off of the file.  Doing so, however, has caused the following exceptions to be thrown by PowerShell.

> -- Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The '<' character, hexadecimal value
>   0x3C, cannot be included in a name. Line 132, position 61."
>
> -- You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Here is my code:

```cs
$xmlfile = [xml](gc "C:\Temp\build.xml" | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "1.1-*", "1.0"}) 

$name = $xmlfile.SelectSingleNode("//name").'#text'  
$result = $xmlfile.SelectSingleNode("//result").'#text' 
$status = $xmlfile.SelectSingleNode("//status").'#text'
$workspace = $xmlfile.SelectSingleNode("//workspace").'#text' 
$id = $workspace.Split("\")[3]  

[PSCustomObject]@{
    "Name" = $name
    "Result" = $result
    "Status " = $status 
    "Id" = $id
}
```

I have tried different ways to load the XML file to include something similar to this:

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$file = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file.Load($fullpath)
```

**Update:**

Xml File

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<build>
  <actions>
    <hudson.model.CauseAction>
      <causeBag class="linked-hash-map">
        <entry>
          <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger_-TimerTriggerCause/>
          <int>1</int>
        </entry>
      </causeBag>
    </hudson.model.CauseAction>
    <hudson.model.ParametersAction>
      <safeParameters class="sorted-set"/>
      <parameters>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>env_webdep</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>https://---</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>env_webdep</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>&quot;Default Web Site\QA505&quot;</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>env_WEBMSDeployServiceURL</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>https://---</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>env_WS5MSDeployServiceURL</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>https://---</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>env_webdep</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>&quot;Default Web Site\Test&quot;</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>env_webdep</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>https://---</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
          <name>system_MinorVersion</name>
          <description></description>
          <value>2</value>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterValue>
      </parameters>
    </hudson.model.ParametersAction>
    <jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction plugin="metrics@4.0.2.4">
      <queuingDurationMillis>28</queuingDurationMillis>
      <blockedDurationMillis>0</blockedDurationMillis>
      <buildableDurationMillis>16</buildableDurationMillis>
      <waitingDurationMillis>4</waitingDurationMillis>
    </jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction>
    <hudson.plugins.tfs.model.WorkspaceConfiguration plugin="tfs@5.142.0">
      <workspaceName>Hudson-V5.0.5-MASTER</workspaceName>
      <workfolder>.</workfolder>
      <projectPath>$/Test/Dev</projectPath>
      <serverUrl>http://---</serverUrl>
      <workspaceExists>true</workspaceExists>
      <cloakedPaths class="list"/>
    </hudson.plugins.tfs.model.WorkspaceConfiguration>
    <hudson.plugins.tfs.TFSRevisionState plugin="tfs@5.142.0">
      <changesetVersion>15919</changesetVersion>
      <projectPath>$/Warehouse/Development/v5.0.5/Web/eOPF</projectPath>
    </hudson.plugins.tfs.TFSRevisionState>
    <com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.FirstCheckoutCompletedInvisibleAction plugin="cloudbees-bitbucket-branch-source@2.4.4"/>
    <hudson.plugins.sonar.AbstractMsBuildSQRunner_-SonarQubeScannerMsBuildParams plugin="sonar@2.8.1">
      <scannerName></scannerName>
      <sqServerName>Sonar</sqServerName>
    </hudson.plugins.sonar.AbstractMsBuildSQRunner_-SonarQubeScannerMsBuildParams>
    <hudson.plugins.sonar.action.SonarAnalysisAction plugin="sonar@2.8.1">
      <installationName>Sonar</installationName>
      <ceTaskId>---</ceTaskId>
      <url>http://---</url>
      <serverUrl>http://---</serverUrl>
      <isNew>true</isNew>
      <isSkipped>false</isSkipped>
    </hudson.plugins.sonar.action.SonarAnalysisAction>
    <com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildAction plugin="rebuild@1.30"/>
    <hudson.plugins.sonar.action.SonarCacheAction plugin="sonar@2.8.1">
      <infoByTaskId>
        <entry>
          <string>AWyNM5URegtpdeQmm-hw</string>
          <hudson.plugins.sonar.client.ProjectInformation>
            <created>1565737138064</created>
            <name>web001</name>
            <url>http://---</url>
            <status>ERROR</status>
            <ceStatus>success</ceStatus>
            <ceUrl>http://---</ceUrl>
          </hudson.plugins.sonar.client.ProjectInformation>
        </entry>
      </infoByTaskId>
      <lastRequest>55555</lastRequest>
      <lastProjInfo>
        <hudson.plugins.sonar.client.ProjectInformation reference="../../infoByTaskId/entry/hudson.plugins.sonar.client.ProjectInformation"/>
      </lastProjInfo>
    </hudson.plugins.sonar.action.SonarCacheAction>
  </actions>
  <queueId>001</queueId>
  <timestamp>1565736843074</timestamp>
  <startTime>1565736843120</startTime>
  <result>SUCCESS</result>
  <duration>294903</duration>
  <charset>windows-1252</charset>
  <keepLog>false</keepLog>
  <builtOn></builtOn>
  <workspace>C:\Jenkins\workspace\test</workspace>
  <hudsonVersion>2.173</hudsonVersion>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.tfs.ChangeSetReader" plugin="tfs@5.142.0"/>
  <culprits class="com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableSortedSet">
    <string>domain</string>
  </culprits>
</build>
```

I've also tried to escape the version `"1\.1-\*", "1.0"` but it causes the application to throw multiple exceptions and doesn't display anything.

Comment: Can you post an example of your XML? It is difficult to trouble-shoot without an example.

Comment: escape your regex pattern: `-replace "1\.1-\*", "1.0"`

Comment: After deleting the spaces before the periods after the $xmlfile's, it seems to work fine, although the selectsinglenode methods come up empty.

Comment: What spaces are you referring to? @js2010  I've gotten it to work and then get the selectsinglenode to be empty as well.  Not sure what is going on there.

Comment: `$name = $xmlfile .SelectSingleNode("//name").'#text';  
$result = $xmlfile .SelectSingleNode("//result").'#text'; 
$status = $xmlfile .SelectSingleNode("//status").'#text';`  I get a syntax error with these spaces before the ".SelectSingleNode("'s.  There's no name, result, or status nodes in the xml.  I don't see why the selectsinglenode's would come up with anything.
`

Comment: Made updates to the xml and SelectSingleNode.  The spaces aren't there in my script.

Comment: I understand removing the addresses for privacy. Is this a typo, or is the tag really missing the `<` : `<value>https://---/value>` under: `env_WEBMSDeployServiceURL`

Comment: privacy @jrider

Comment: @developer_117 the xml is built without the ending `</` on some tags ?

Comment: No, there are no errors (closing tags) from the xml aside from me trying to convert the xml.

Comment: @jrider  I agree.. "<" is missing in two places.

Comment: Fixed the two missing "<".

Comment: It works fine for me know, except $workspace is null because there's no changelog nodes.

Comment: It should work now. I ran a quick test and it converts it to a valid xml object. js2010 is correct. The line: `$id = $workspace.Split("\")[3] ` will not work because `$workspace = $xmlfile.SelectSingleNode("//changelog").'#text` is null. There is no `changelog` node in this xml

Comment: Updated the SelectSingleNode("//changlog").'#text' to workspace.  I was always able to read the file and display the object but the issue is I still get the exception message above with it.  The "Cannot convert value" error.  I am trying to remove that exception from displaying and run the process cleanly.

Comment: @developer_117 After the corrections to the OP it appears to be running correctly. The $xmlfile is the loaded xml. Sorry, I am confused on what you are trying to do. Is there more code that you are running that isnt posted?

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help.  @JosefZ solution solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$xmlfile = [xml]( ( Get-Content "C:\Temp\build.xml" ) -replace "xml\sversion='1\.1'", "xml version='1.0'" )
```

Explanation:

- Do not bother about `ForEach-Object` as [the `-replace` operator will execute on each item in an array](https://powershellexplained.com/2018-10-15-Powershell-arrays-Everything-you-wanted-to-know/#-replace-and--split).
- Regular expression extended to `"xml\sversion='1\.1'"` to keep other `'1.1'` values unchanged (if any in an input file).

Running improved code gives the following output:

> ```
> Name       Result  Status Id  
> ----       ------  ------ --  
> env_webdep SUCCESS ERROR  test
> ```

BTW, (*a guess only*) you may be interested in using

```
$id = $workspace.Split("\")[-1]
```

or

```
$id = $workspace | Split-Path -Leaf
```

instead of

```
$id = $workspace.Split("\")[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to reproduce the first two errors.

As a C# developer I can tell you that the first error stems from `ForEach-Object` because it returns an `Object[]` of string objects (it doesn't know they're strings of course) and tries to convert them into an `XmlDocument` because of `[xml]` but a `System.Object[]` has no way to convert to an `XmlDocument` so an error is thrown. You need to convert the `Object[]` into an `XmlNode[]` and then into an `XmlDocument` object for the parsing further down. This can be accomplished using `Select-Xml -Content` after altering it.

```bsh
$xmlfile = Select-Xml -Content (gc "C:\Temp\build.xml" | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "1.1-*","1.0"})
```

This is most likely to work because of the `String[]` specified in `-Content` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6#parameters

Edit: if the XML is malformed or corrupted then that and similar errors will be thrown

Comment: Implemented what you have here @Alexander Bielby and am now getting prompted to enter an XPath upon running.  `cmdlet Select-Xml at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
XPath: `

Comment: This is what I did - `$report = "C:\Temp\report.xml"
$xml = gc "C:\Temp\build.xml" | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "1.1-*","1.0"} | Set-Content -Path $report -Force
$name = Select-Xml -path $xml -XPath "//@name"` But I comeback to the same issue when trying to `Select-Xml -Path` - `cannot be read: The '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C, cannot be included in a name`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the error I get:

> Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type
>   "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The 'value' start tag on line 28
>   position 12 does not match the end tag of
>   'hudson.model.StringParameterValue'. Line 29, position 11."

Missing "<" on line 28 for one thing.
Missing "<" line 62.
There's no changelog nodes.

Comment: If these xml files are auto-generated through Jenkins then I don't want to have to go in and alter every xml file to get it to work.  Is there another way to convert the xml without having to parse the xml file?

Comment: You don't have to use [xml] if you just want to search and replace the text.  Jenkins generates invalid xml?

Comment: I'm trying to read information from the xml document.  The only reason I am trying to replace the version is to read the xml. I can read it now but I have that exception message above when executing.